# How do I stop my long <select> dropdown list text from being shortened on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, ios

How do I prevent my `<select>` option text from being shortened?

I’ve got the following HTML:

```
<select>
<option value="23007">Rolled (NOT FRAMED) (included)</option> 
<option value="23005">Gallery Wrap Stretched Canvas 1.5&quot; deep (add $63)</option> 
<option value="23006">Gallery Wrap Stretched Canvas 3/4&quot; deep (add $45)</option> 
<option value="23008">Silver Metal Frame (add $37)</option> 
<option value="23003">Premium Black Wood Frame - 1.6&quot; wide (add $60)</option> 
<option value="23004">Premium Black Wood Frame - 1.2&quot; wide (add $48)</option>
</select>
```

When I view it in Mobile Safari on iPhone, only start and end characters of each option are displayed — most of the middle characters are replaced with just `...`.

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: "Visit this link m.ateemo.com/products/warhol-style-1-panel-13x13-inch?cPath=22 on your iphone, scroll down and select frame and mounting." Could you post a screenshot instead?

Comment: Here it is http://i.imgur.com/2L1H1.png

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can't. That's a native browser component. If you would prefer something else, you'd need to write your own UI component in javascript.

Form a UX perspective, I'd suggest that the better UI would be a radio button list:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html

Answer (score 1):

I see your issue. I’ve got a reduced test case here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/GG8eU/3/

When I view tap on the `<select>` in iOS 4.3 on my iPhone, the text displayed in the iPhone’s selection popup is actually reduced in size so that it’s all viewable.

What version of iOS are you using?

[image]

Comment: Wow! Apple must have made that part of the updates. Nice feature.

Comment: @DA: pretty essential feature, I’d say. Granted, really long `<select>`s are relatively rare and possibly a bad idea, but making them unreadable (like in the old iOS) isn’t good.

Comment: @Paul: I'm using 4.2.1 (8C148a)

Comment: @Tri: looks like it was fixed in 4.3 then. I don’t have 4.2 here, so I can’t try any fixes I’m afraid.